# Is Laravel's 'pluck' method cheaper than a general 'get'?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to dramatically cut down on pricey DB queries for an app I'm building, and thought I should perhaps just return IDs of a child collection (then find the related object from my React state), rather than returning the children themselves.

I suppose I'm asking, if I use *'pluck'* to just return child IDs, is that more efficient than a general *'get'*, or would I be wasting my time with that?

Comment: yes i guess it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,**pluck** method is just fine if you are trying to retrieving a Single Column from tables.

If you use **get()** method it will retrieve all information about child model and that could lead to a little slower process for querying and get results.

So in my opinion, You are using great method for retrieving the result.

Laravel has also different methods for select queries. Here you can look [Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects).

Answer (score 1):

The good practice to perform DB select query in a application, is to select columns that are necessary. If `id` column is needed, then `id` column should be selected, instead of all columns. Otherwise, it will spend unnecessary memory to hold unused data. If your mind is clear, `pluck` and `get` are the same:

```
Model::pluck('id')

// which is the same as

Model::select('id')->get()->pluck('id');

// which is the same as

Model::get(['id'])->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm a little late to the party, but i was wondering this myself and i decided to research it. It proves that one method is faster than the other.

Using `Model::select('id')->get()` is faster than `Model::get()->pluck('id')`.

This is because `Illuminate\Support\Collection::pluck` will iterate over each returned `Model` and extract only the selected column(s) using a PHP foreach loop, while the first method will make it cheaper in general as it is a database query instead.