# Laravent Eloquent Error When Trying to Perform a Not Equal Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my database, I have a table for `roles`

there are three roles, Admin, Regional Admin, and User

From my controller, I'm trying to select roles where the role name does not equal to "Admin".

Following is my `eloquent`

```
$roles = Role::pluck('name','name')->where('name','<>','Admin')->get();
```

But this gives me an error saying

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed..
```

When I changed my `eloquent` to

```
$roles = Role::pluck('name','name')->where('name','<>','Admin')->all();
```

it works but it'll give me all the records including the 'Admin'

Where do I need to fix in order to perform the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM `roles` WHERE name <> 'Admin'
```

I'm using those values in my blade as a dropdown options

```
{{ Form::select('roles',array_merge(['' => 'Veuillez sélectionner un rôle'],  $roles ), Request::old('Roles'),array('class' => 'form-control txt_txt')) }}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587457/difference-between-eloquent-modelget-and-all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421317/is-laravels-pluck-method-cheaper-than-a-general-get

Comment: I'm not even sure the `pluck()` method exists on the Eloquent query builder, only on the collection class, and you certainly shouldn't be using it before a WHERE clause. If you only need one field you should use `select()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would try using **!=** rather than **<>**, otherwise it seems fine :)

```
$roles = Role::pluck('name','name')->where('name','!=','Admin')->all();
```

Comment: This gives all the records, but I want to drop Admins

Answer (score 0):

** Edited based on the change to question

```
// Get the name of all Roles except 'Admin' as array
$names = Role::where('name','<>','Admin')->pluck('name')->toArray();

// use $names as keys and values
$roles = array_combine($names, $names);
```

Then `$roles` can use in `array_merge(['' => 'Veuillez sélectionner un rôle'],  $roles )` to be the values using in blade.